# PHP - Validate an XML against an online DTD file

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, dtd, xml-validation

I have a xml file and I would like to validate it with a DTD.

For that, I included the DTD link in the XML:

```
<!DOCTYPE article SYSTEM "http://dtd.nlm.nih.gov/1.1/journalpublishing.dtd">
```

And then did:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($xml);

if ($dom->validate()) {
    echo "This document is valid!\n";exit;
}
else {
    var_dump("Not OK");exit;
}
```

The problem is that I am getting this warning message:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::validate(http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 500 Server Error
```

Any idea? Thank you.

Comment: change `loadHTML` to `load` unless you want to trigger libxml's HTML parser module

Comment: Could you please answer the question and maybe provide some detail why load works and not loadXML ?

Comment: Done, actually I meant `loadXML`, not `load`. That is, unless your `$xml` var holds a filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method to load the XML.

Use [`load`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) to load an XML file or [loadXML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) to load an XML string. Use [loadHTMLFile](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) to load an HTML file and [loadHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to load HTML content.

Using one of the HTML methods will trigger [libxml's HTML parser module](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html), which is

> an HTML 4.0 non-verifying parser with API compatible with the XML parser ones. It should be able to parse "real world" HTML, even if severely broken from a specification point of view.

The HTML Parser module will always use HTML4 Transitional as the DTD, as well as parsing the document with lenient error handling and attempting to auto correct things, for instance, by adding an HTML skeleton to partials, etc.